# How to spread the Views in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello people i am developing a LogIn activity in Android. But i am not able to locate the views correctly

What i want is to spread all the views in a proportional way to all devices, but when i use dp to set a margin or a place and i put the device landscape some of the views dont fit in the screen

I was looking for a sort of layout_weight but without changin the size , what i want is to locate all the views proportionally according to the available space, no matter the device size or orientation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="errorsion" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/User"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/Username"
            android:maxHeight="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Pass"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/Pass"
            android:onClick="LogIn" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:text="@string/Log" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in a small device the Log In Button is missing

https://scontent-b-mia.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/t1.0-9/10338845_10201072685859855_2362465558048942798_n.jpg

Comment: Can you post your layout xml code?

Comment: What issues are you facing while using layout_weight?

Comment: What Distwo and Aashish said. Furthermore, a sketch of for example a phone layout and a tablet layout would be helpful to determine exactly what you mean.

Comment: Press ctrl+shift+f in your layout files. They look messy.

Comment: As @Aashish said, next time please format your code before pasting here, especially if it is so long. It's much easier to help if you take the time, and give your code some structure.

Comment: what do you mean with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your entire view inside `ScrollView` to make the `login` button appear:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match-parent"
    android:layout_height="match-parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match-parent"
        android:layout_height="match-parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

`layout_weight` divides the remaining view in proportions. Here remaining means what is left after applying `layout_width` and `layout_height`. So, to make it work perfectly, you should assign `0dp` to these.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Comment: This will not display all the views proportionally.

Comment: Why not? I am assuming the OP is applying layout_weight.

Comment: He was using fixed width, not layout weights for his editText, see his code above.

Comment: My bad, I missed it. Anyways, my answer makes it clear. Make layout_width="0dp". Isn't it clear?

Comment: This could help if the button does no fit, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you can play with the layout weight values to make your fields bigger or smaller. Also put back your @string for your hints, I hard coded them for my preview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="5">
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="errorsion"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="30dp">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/User"
                    android:maxHeight="50dp"
                    android:hint="username" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="30dp">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/Pass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="LogIn"
                    android:hint="Password" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Login"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```